# How does Chronometer work after the setBase?

Tags: android

When I put some random number in the setBase some crazy time appeared, but when I put the SystemClock.elapsedRealtime or current, it works fine, what I don't understand is why. I know that setBase receives a number to be a reference, but how they know the time I passed is the elapsedRealtime, they compare the numbers? Because any other number different from the defaults ones(elapsed,current) doesnt work fine.

Comment: Could you provide an example or two? What random numbers did you pass and what was the crazy time?

Comment: I passed 0 and also 10000, in the second example, the chronometer was like: 00:00 ... 00:0* ... 00:0)